# Nested data from generator causes TypeError: All the elements of `output_signature` must be `tf.TypeSpec` objects

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a Dataset using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` with a generator that yields data in the form of `[x, mx, y, my], z`, which is the format that the model requires for input. I'm attempting to create the dataset with:

```
   dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
      data_generator, 
      args=[train_file], 
      output_signature=([tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, None), dtype=tf.float32),
                        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, None), dtype=tf.int8),
                        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, None), dtype=tf.int8),
                        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, None), dtype=tf.int8)],
                        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, None, tgt_vocab_size), dtype=tf.int8)))
```

but it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/ui/abv/hoangsx/synthesis/temp/test_dataset.py", line 116, in <module>
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, None, tgt_vocab_size), dtype=tf.int8)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 538, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 818, in from_generator
    raise TypeError("All the elements of `output_signature` must be "
TypeError: All the elements of `output_signature` must be `tf.TypeSpec` objects.
```

is there any way to make this work?